# Subdivision Surface being disabled

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry

I have tried to apply this modifier but it says that it is disabled and its icon is red.I used decimate geometry previously on the object I'm trying to apply this modifier to so I think that that might be part of the problem.

https://we.tl/t-4Jty9PXDuk

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: No chance you're trying to apply it in edit mode, are you? Modifiers can only be applied in object mode.

Comment: Im making a grape and Im trying to apply the modifier on all the grapes. You can download my .blend file from this link https://we.tl/t-4Jty9PXDuk

Comment: No I made sure I tried applying in object mode but it still didnt work

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.